# ERROR: ChatConnector: startConversation - error starting conversation

Tags: node.js, bots, skype, botframework

I am using the code below to send a reply to a message in a server-less/event-driven architecture where I don't have access to the session/dialog. This was working fine for weeks until last week friday. The messages are send to a skype user, this is still working fine in the Now I am seeing 400 error messages. I am using botbuilder@3.5.4 and node version 6.9.2.

```
ERROR: ChatConnector: startConversation - error starting conversation.
Error: Request to 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations' failed: [400] Bad Request
```

Code:

```
const connector = new botbuilder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "addId",
    appPassword: "pwd"
});

var bot = new botbuilder.UniversalBot(connector);
var property = {}; //extracted from the incoming message

var address = { 
  "channelId": property.value.channelId,
  "user": property.value.from,
  "bot": property.value.recipient,
  "serviceUrl": property.value.serviceUrl,
  "useAuth": true };

var msg = new botbuilder.Message();

msg.address(address)
       .text("hello");

bot.send(msg);
```

Comment: You may need to define the botbuilder that you are using in the first line like this: var botbuilder = require('botbuilder');

Comment: true true, that was the case. it turns out that this was a skype issue, all working fine now.